# Freezing and Unfreezing network layers in TF Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am using the TF Estimator to train my model on a dataset. For the first few training iterations, I want to freeze certain layers in the network. For the remaining iterations I want to unfreeze these layers.

I found some solutions where we have two different optimizer train_ops in the estimator's model_fn.

```
def ModelFunction(features, labels, mode, params):
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        layerTrainingVars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, "LayerName")
        #Train Op for freezing layers
        freeze_train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step(), var_list=layerTrainingVars)
        #Train Op for training all layers
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
        #Based on whether we want to freeze or not, we send the corresponding train_op to the estimatorSpec. How do I do this?
        estimatorSpec = tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=freeze_train_op)

    return estimatorSpec
```

For the above solution, the corresponding EstimatorSpec could be returned based on the train_op. I tried using the freeze_train_op for a few training iterations, and then killing the process, and changing the train_op to have no layer freezing in the code. After doing this, there is a checkpoint error, which says that the graphs/variables saved in the checkpoints are different. I guess the first set of iterations did not save the frozen layers. How do I switch train_ops programmatically such that checkpointing works too?

Is there any better way to go about freezing/unfreezing layers for training in TF.Estmator?

Answer (score 0):

You can return 2 train_op by grouping them together.

```
def ModelFunction(features, labels, mode, params):
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        layerTrainingVars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, "LayerName")
        #Train Op for freezing layers
        freeze_train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step(), var_list=layerTrainingVars)
        #Train Op for training all layers
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
        estimatorSpec = tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=tf.group(freeze_train_op, train_op))

    return estimatorSpec
```

But this won't take into account different iterations. If you want to train different set of variables on different iterations and don't want to stop training and load weights from checkpoint, you need to use session. Estimator api doesn't allow session management.